# default image for paperclip is not displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

While looping through my objects in a view I am trying to display the first attached image of my listing like this:

```
<%= image_tag listing.assets.first.attachment.url(:small) %>
```

This works fine if all my listings have at least one image but if one listing doesn't have an image, the default image is not shown. Instead I get a undefined method `attachment' for nil:NilClass.

Which is logical because the object is nil but I have this in my model

```
has_attached_file :attachment, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>",
:small => "200x200>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url =>
"no_image_:style.jpg"
```

So I assume if image_tag doesn't receive aI url it should display "no_image_small.jpg" which is in my **app/assets/images** folder.

Is that how it should work? How can I display my no_image_small.jpg if the image doesn't exist and is nill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im guessing that you have a Listing model that looks something like this:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets
  ...
end
```

And a asset class like this

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :attachment, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", 
  :small => "200x200>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, 
  :default_url => "no_image_:style.jpg"
  ...
end
```

The problem is not paperclip or you setup, but that the listing don't have any associated assets.

### Edit:

Here is a solution to still get the default image, from the association:

```
<% asset = listing.assets.first || listing.assets.build %> 
<%= image_tag asset.attachment.url(:small) %>
```

Comment: This seems to work: <% if listing.assets.any?%> <%=image_tag listing.assets.first.attachment.url(:small) %>  but it would be nice if it could put the default image if there are no assets

Comment: Sure. Why do you have a seperate assets model? Is there other things then listings that have assets? You could do something like `<% if listing.assets.any?%> <%=image_tag listing.assets.first.attachment.url(:small) %> <% else %> <%=image_tag listing.assets.build.attachment.url(:small) %> <% end %>` maybe with a bit of refactoring

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Since I have multiple photos for each listing, and I might have a gallery of photos I assumed that having a seperate model for assets might be a good idea. Also I might manage other types of attachments in the future. Is the recommended approach for paperclip is using the main model as as the asset model?